# SASS - Bootstrap 3 GRID and Navbar only - how?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-sass

How I can import Bootstrap 3  `grid` and `navbar` to my .sass file?

I tried:

```
@import bootstrap/variables
@import bootstrap/mixins
//@import bootstrap/mixins/grid-framework
//@import bootstrap/mixins/grid
@import bootstrap/normalize
@import bootstrap/scaffolding
@import bootstrap/print
@import bootstrap/type
@import bootstrap/grid
@import bootstrap/responsive-utilities
@import bootstrap/navbar
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: No mixin named form-inline
```

What is correct way to import a Bootstrap 3 (bootstrap-sass) grid and `navbar` to my project?

I can't find all mixins manually, that's why I need to import `mixins.scss` file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only had luck importing it the entire suite of sass files, and then commenting out components I know I'm not using in the _bootstrap.scss. You may end up with more than you like to prevent errors.

From the bootstrap SASS github:

> By default all of Bootstrap is imported.
>
> You can also import components explicitly. To start with a full list
>   of modules copy _bootstrap.scss file into your assets as
>   _bootstrap-custom.scss. Then comment out components you do not want from _bootstrap-custom. In the application Sass file, replace @import
>   'bootstrap' with:
>
> @import 'bootstrap-custom';

Comment: Importing _bootstrap, but when I trying to import only components what i would actually use, then it is a total headache for me ("no mixin named xxxxx" etc)..  

Or what is the best practice? Importing _bootstrap.scss and commenting out components, what i don't use?  

Actually it's same, yes.

Comment: You are safest to start with the whole suite, then comment out components you know you aren't using.  I usually comment out a few, test it out, comment out a few more until errors appear.  It isn't ideal :)  But I do believe bootstrap 4 is switching completely to SASS, so maybe it will improve in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is not add the whole library. You need to include _forms.css to get the form-inline mixin.

```
@import bootstrap/_forms;
```